# failing to connecting to firebase database using the php unofficial sdk

Tags: php, firebase

I'm having challenges connect to my firebase database using the PHP unofficial sdk via composer

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without you giving specific information, I can tell you have installed a 5.x release of the SDK and are working with an outdated tutorial on the internet . You can find the documentation of the SDK at https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/setup.html

Comment: thanks i will go just that